# Building pandoc into yocto core-image-minimal

Tags: build, pandoc, yocto

I'm doing a yocto build for an Altera ARM processor.  I'm trying to build the userland for core-image-minimal and I run into a dependency on pandoc.  Whats the best way to add pandoc to the yocto build?

Answer (score 0):

In case that You want to add some package into image, *Yocto* framework provide the [IMAGE_INSTALL](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-IMAGE_INSTALL) variable:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " pandoc"
```